# Airflow HTTP call from unreliable network

Tags: airflow

I need to fetch data from REST API via HTTP get on apache airflow (e.g. to https://something.com/api/data).
The data is come in pages with following structure :

```json
{
  "meta" : {
    "size" : 50,
    "currentPage" : 3,
    "totalPage" : 10
  },
  "data" : [
    ....
  ]
}
```

The problem is, the API provider is not reliable. Sometimes we get 504 gateway timeout. So I have to retry the API call, until current page = total page, and retry if we got 504 Gateway timeout. However, the overall retry process must not exceed 15 minutes.

Is there any way I can achieve this using apache airflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [HTTP Operator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/operators.html#http-operators) from [HTTP providers package](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-http/stable/index.html). Check the examples and guide in those links.

If you don't have it already, start by installing the provider package:
`pip install apache-airflow-providers-http`

Then you could try it sending requests to https://httpbin.org .To do so, create a connection like:

[image: http_conn screenshot]

You could create Tasks using the `SimpleHttpOperator`:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.http.operators.http import SimpleHttpOperator

with DAG(
    'example_http_operator',
    default_args={
        'retries': 1,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    },
    start_date=datetime(2021, 10, 9),
) as dag:

    task_get_op = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_op',
        method='GET',
        endpoint='get',
        data={"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"},
        headers={},
    )
```

By default, under the hood, this operator performs a [raise_for_status](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#requests.Response.raise_for_status) to the obtained response. So, if the response `status_code` is not in the range of 1xx or 2xx will raise an exception and the Task will be mark as `failed`. If you want to customize this behaviour you can provide your own `response_check` as an argument to the `SimpleHttpOperator`

> :param **response_check**: A check against the 'requests' response object.
> The callable takes the response object as the first positional argumentand optionally any number of keyword arguments available in the context dictionary.
> It should return True for 'pass' and False otherwise.
> :type response_check: A lambda or defined function.

Finally to handle retries on failures as needed, you could use the following parameters avaiblables in any Operator in Airflow ([docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html)):

> **retries** (int) -- the number of retries that should be performed before failing the task

> **retry_delay** (datetime.timedelta) -- delay between retries

> **retry_exponential_backoff** (bool) -- allow progressive longer waits between retries by using exponential backoff algorithm on retry delay (delay will be converted into seconds)

> **max_retry_delay** (datetime.timedelta) -- maximum delay interval between retries

Finally, to try out how everything works together, perform a request to an endpoint which will answer with an specific error status code:

```py
    task_get_op = SimpleHttpOperator(
        task_id='get_op',
        method='GET',
        endpoint='status/400', # response stus code will be 400 
        data={"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"},
        headers={},
    )
```

Let me know if that works for you!

Comment: The unreliable network might be solved with that, but I don't see how we can "loop" this operator. The endpoint has pagination on it, which can be dynamic (today 20 pages, tomorrow 50 pages), so I need to check the "meta" response, and dynamically increase the parameter on url : https://something.com/api/data?page=xxx but I don't see any way to do such "loop"?

Comment: The retry related params I mentioned, won't give you the dynamic behaviour you are looking for. They will retry the same Task as it was the first time. I guess I missed that from you question. You could definetly extend this `SimpleHTTPOperator`, as any other OP, create your own Operator from it and apply any extra logic that you need. [This guide](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/custom-operator.html) from the docs may help you out.